# What is a proper alternative for pluck(col_name)

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

This is a pretty common operation in my toolbox.
I want a pure tidyverse solution without using a character.

```r
suppressWarnings(library(tidyverse))
tibble(a=1) %>% pluck('a')
#> [1] 1
tibble(a=1) %>% pluck(a)
#> Error in list2(...): object 'a' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `pull`

```
tibble(a =1) %>%
   pull(a)
[1] 1
```

---

Or if we want to use `pluck`

```
tibble(a=1) %>% 
 pluck(deparse(substitute(a)))
[1] 1
```